# Android SQLite, create db with 4 columns and insert values

Tags: android, sqlite, sdk, insert

I am missing something with all of the android SQLite tutorials.

I want to create a SQLite database that holds the autoincrementing key, and four text fields that I will pass in

I intend to pass in this SQL database

`private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + "(field1) values (?)" + "(field2) values (?)" + "(field3) values (?)";`

but I'm not sure if the android sdk has a proper insert function.

I'm not sure how "Cursor" relates to anything I am trying to do, and I'm not sure how much object oriented initializing I should be trying to as opposed to just calling some built in android sdk functions.

insight appreciated, but please break it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will recommend you to go through NotePad exercise here is a [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html). Specially go through Exercise 1.

And for more depth knowledge you can go through project which I have created. Here is a [link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/tree/master/src/com/feedReader/provider)

Look for creatFeed function call [here](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/provider/FeedDetailProvider.java). I think will help to answer your problem.

Comment: the creatFeed class looks very relevant to what I am trying to do. Which class do you call it and do the inserts and other queries in? FeedDB it seems

Comment: I call it from RSSHandler class here is [link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/detail/RSSHandler.java) and look at line 160. Sorry man, do not have good comments. Still working on this project. And rest of the queries I call from this class here is [link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/detail/FeedDetailActivity.java)

Comment: @RD, If answer helped you to resolve your problem, will appreciate if you can tick and accept my answer. Will help me to increase my reputation. Thanks.